# EventHubTrigger in functions v1 - set initialOffsetOptions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When working with Azure Functions v2 (and higher) and Event Hub it's possible to configure the location in the event stream from which to start processing using the `initialOffsetOptions`/`type` [setting in host.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings):

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs":
            "initialOffsetOptions": {
                "type": "fromStart",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck with v1 because of some external dependencies so I'm really curious to see if it's possible to configure a similar setting in previous versions and if it's not (which seems to be the most likely scenario as this is a feature which was [released on Dec 2020](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/releases/tag/v4.2.0)), **what the default behaviour is** in v1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V1, we don't have the option `initialOffsetOptions` in `host.json`. The default behavior in V1 is that it starts from the very beginning of the event stream(Like specify `fromStart` for `initialOffsetOptions` in V2 or higher.).

This new feature of `initialOffsetOptions` is requested by this github issue: [Allow users to specify offset / timestamp to configure starting point for Event Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/issues/64). In this issue, it stated the previous behavior.